# Display all internet connections during startup

Tags: debugging, networking

How can I display all Internet connections that are used during startup? Sometimes I work in a low speed Internet environment and I would like to remove all the Internet connection code during startup.

**Update**: strace shows that Emacs stucks when it tries to connect to dbus, but I have no idea why...

Comment: An easy solution is just flipping the WiFi switch while starting Emacs.

Comment: I don't think that emacs tries to connect to the Internet by default; unless you explicitly call certain commands which will obviously do that. For example: `M-x list packages`.

Comment: @xuhdev is there any reason you can't use a traditional packet sniffer to determine what connections are being made?

Comment: bisect your code, I had similar issue before. In my case, it's some legacy flymake file. https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d/commit/6e7237f

Comment: @chenbin Interesting... My bisecting shows there's something to do with magit, but I still have no idea why...

Comment: best thing you can do is design a minimum test case and report the issue to magit developer.